# div onclick does not fire (css-animated arrow, possible div size/overlaying issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using an animated arrow with the following code:

```js
function startDownload() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

```css
.arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.1s;
    width: 80px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.arrow-top, .arrow-bottom {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 4px;
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

    .arrow-top:after, .arrow-bottom:after {
        background-color: #fff;
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transition: all 0.15s;
    }

.arrow-top {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}

    .arrow-top:after {
        left: 100%;
        right: 0;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

.arrow-bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
}

    .arrow-bottom:after {
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
        transition-delay: 0.15s;
    }

.arrow:hover .arrow-top:after {
    left: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow-bottom:after {
    right: 0;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.arrow:active {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: black;
        /*background-color: #2B2A3F;*/
    }
</style>

<div class="arrow" id="start-arrow" onclick="startDownload()" style="z-index: 10;">
    <div class="arrow-top" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
    <div class="arrow-bottom" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
</div>
```

The issue is that when I click on the two arrow lines, the onclick() does not work. It works only if I click in the surrounding area of the two lines, that is enclosed by the border of the parent div with id `start-arrow`.

The desired behavior is for the `onclick` to work in the entire area enclosed by the `start-arrow` div.

I tried using `z-index` to make the `start-arrow` div be on top, but it's not working. I tried messing with `display` and also with `position` of the elements in CSS but no luck as well. However I should mention that I'm looking for a solution that does not include changing the `position` attributes of the elements.

How can I make the `onclick` fire regardless of where I click in the `start-arrow` div area?

EDIT: it seems to be working a lot better inside Stack Overflow, why? However if a click on top of the border of each line, it doesn't always work. I am opening mine (exact same code) in Firefox (it doesn't work inside my asp.net either).

Comment: So there is something else in your page that is affecting this, are there any errors in console? Duplicate ids? Broken html?

Comment: I am testing with the exact same code on Firefox as in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't we simply wrap the elements into another parent element and bind the event on that? I am able to solve it using a parent element ('parent-id').

```js
function startDownload() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

```css
.arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.1s;
    width: 80px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.arrow-top, .arrow-bottom {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 4px;
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

    .arrow-top:after, .arrow-bottom:after {
        background-color: #fff;
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transition: all 0.15s;
    }

.arrow-top {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}

    .arrow-top:after {
        left: 100%;
        right: 0;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

.arrow-bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
}

    .arrow-bottom:after {
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
        transition-delay: 0.15s;
    }

.arrow:hover .arrow-top:after {
    left: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow-bottom:after {
    right: 0;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.arrow:active {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: black;
        /*background-color: #2B2A3F;*/
    }
</style>

<div id="parent-id" onclick="startDownload()">
  <div class="arrow" id="start-arrow"  style="z- 
   index: 10;">
      <div class="arrow-top" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
      <div class="arrow-bottom" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("start-arrow");
for(let element of parent.children){
element.addEventListener("click", startDownload)
}

function startDownload() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

```css
.arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.1s;
    width: 80px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.arrow-top, .arrow-bottom {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 4px;
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

    .arrow-top:after, .arrow-bottom:after {
        background-color: #fff;
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transition: all 0.15s;
    }

.arrow-top {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}

    .arrow-top:after {
        left: 100%;
        right: 0;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

.arrow-bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
}

    .arrow-bottom:after {
        left: 0;
        right: 100%;
        transition-delay: 0.15s;
    }

.arrow:hover .arrow-top:after {
    left: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow-bottom:after {
    right: 0;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.arrow:active {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: black;
        /*background-color: #2B2A3F;*/
    }
</style>

<div class="arrow" id="start-arrow" onclick="startDownload()" style="z-index: 10;">
    <div class="arrow-top" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
    <div class="arrow-bottom" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
</div>
```

This is not  the most optimize solution, but it should do the trick, other solution is to increase click box by adding it padding.

```
let parent = document.getElementById("filterInput");
for(let element of parent.children){
element.addEventListener("click", startDownload)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're attaching a click event listener. That means if you want it to fire, the element needs to be clicked & released.
If you click on your element, it moves to the upper-left. Now if you're slow enough the element isn't below your mouse pointer anymore, thus the click event won't fire because you released the mouse somewhere below.
So simply replace

```
onclick="startDownload()"
```

by

```
onmousedown="startDownload()"
```

and make sure you don't have an alert dialog in the callback function since it would stop the movement of your arrow. Simply trace something using console.log("fired");

Answer (score -1):

Do it with jquery. Use the id **start-arrow**

```
<div class="arrow" id="start-arrow" onclick="startDownload()" style="z-index: 10;">
    <div class="arrow-top" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
    <div class="arrow-bottom" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 9;"></div>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#start-arrow',function(){
  alert('Hi');
});
```

Comment: Using jQuery can not remove the original problem, it's just a javascript-library.

Comment: You need to trigger just? or what's the issue occurred if you used the jquery?